# Processing a huge amount of records in a FOR LOOP in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have an Oracle (11g) database with a table with about 200 millions of records. I have to modify two columns of each row in the table. What would be the most efficient solution for this?

I tried using a code similiar to the following, but after a while the execution crashed due to `ORA-04030 - Out of process memory`.

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE BAR > 2000)
    LOOP
        -- Do the processing and update row
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I can't change any OS-level parameters. I have to solve this using the code.

Comment: Why do you need PL/SQL if you could do it in pure SQL?

Comment: If you are truly looking for most efficient, you will select the 200 million into a new table, updating the columns at the same time, then switching out the new table for the old.  Doing this in a loop in PL/SQL is actually the slowest way to do this.

Comment: **I have to iterate over...**  - why? That is a very unusual requirement. The much more common type of requirement is "I have to modify two columns of each row in a table with about 200 million rows" - the requirement only tells you **what** needs to be done, not **how** to do it. Note also that tables in a relational database have rows, not records.

Comment: @mathguy Than I really apologize here for my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know the exact column modifications, I'll just make something up; lets say I need to change the name to be lowercase but the first letter in caps and that I have to give a salary rise depending on job.
This is the most efficient way.

Let's assume I have a 200M row MYEMP table.

```
create table temp_emp
as select * from myemp
where 1=2;

alter session enable parallel dml

insert /*+ APPEND */ into temp_emp
select 
  EMPNO  
, initcap(ENAME)  
, JOB    
, MGR    
, HIREDATE
, case when job = 'MANAGER' then SAL  * 1.1 else SAL * 1.05 end  
, COMM   
, DEPTNO 
from myemp
;

drop table myemp
;
```

> you could rename rather than drop MYEMP, if you need to be "safe" and
>   double check

```
rename temp_emp to myemp;
```

A quick test, with 14million rows, took 16s, using serial execution. By employing database parallelism, the runtime could be reduced even further.

Comment: Could the UNDO tablespace get full due to all the inserts of 200M records? Would this happen with your example?

Comment: @Javiator. That's one of the benefits of the direct path load ( APPEND hint). The amount of redo is small. My 14M row insert generate about 150k of redo.

Comment: How large in size is your table with 14 million records? My table with 200 million rows is about 30 GB. Would that still be no problem with the UNDO tablespace?`My UNDO tablespace is about 10GB.

Comment: @Javiator It's about 1GB.

Comment: Can I extend the INSERT in such a way that it splits a row into two rows if the length of, e.g. COMM, is greater than 1000 characters? I.e., one row is updated with SUBSTR(COMM, 1, 1000) and the other one is inserted with SUBSTR(COMM, 1001, 2000)?

Comment: @Javiator You could. But why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: I already solved it. Your approach is amazingly fast. By the way, what does the WHERE 1=2 do?

Comment: @Javiator. Can you accept my answer in that case :).  The "where 1=2" will evaluate to false for every row; so it's an easy way to create a table that looks like another table, but with none of the data.

Comment: @Javiator Incidentally, how long does it take now, compared to how long it took before (or at least until it errored)?

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `bulk collect` with `limit`. Only limited rows (as defined by the limit clause) as fetched into the memory, which you can loop over to do the required processing.

```
declare
    cursor cur_foo is
        select * from foo where bar > 2000;
    type tab is table of foo%rowtype;
    v_tab tab;
BEGIN
    open cur_foo;
    loop
        fetch cur_foo bulk collect into v_tab limit 100;
        exit when v_tab.count = 0;

        for idx in 1..v_tab.count loop
            -- do something with v_tab(idx)
        end loop;

    end loop;
    close cur_foo;
END;
```

You can also use `FORALL` to do bulk insert, update or delete operations.

See this article on these features on Oracle website

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html

and this question on AskTOM:

- https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:5918938803188

Comment: Does this iterate over all rows incrementally? I.e., after the first 1000, the next 1000 are fetched?

Comment: @Javiator - Yes. See the first article (link provided in the answer) to understand how it works.

Comment: Could you please show me an example how I can access a single row in the loop?

Comment: @Javiator - Where I have added a comment "do something with v_tab(idx)". The inner loop loops on the 100 (or less in case lesser are available) rows. So you can print a column xyz from each row using `dbms_output.put_line(v_tab(idx).xyz)` inside the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @GurV Is it safe to commit every 30k rows in this loop? I modified my script according to your answer and executed it. I got a ORA-01555 error.